# .htaccess RewriteRule with two variables but show only the last one

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to accomplish the following match:

```
/author.php?author_id=4&author=joe
/joe
```

I can get as far as showing only the author_id, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$  author.php?author_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

But I'm not clear how to proceed from there.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If I understand your question correctly:**

Your problem is essentially you're trying to load two variables from a public URI which you want to contain only one variable:

The browser use links to `/joe` and so somehow htaccess needs to discover both `author_id` and `author` values from this single value text link.

This obviously can't be done.

This sort of issue is one that causes popular mod_rewrites to "folderise" their URLs, such as `/author/4/joe` , so both facets of needed information are present in the URI (`4` and `joe`) but the URI remains "friendly".

To apply this form of solution to your given URI:

```
RewriteRule ^/author/([0-9]+)/?(.*)$ /author.php?author_id=$1&author=$2 [NC,L]
```

- `/author/` == A folder only, useful for user clarity (who or what is Joe?).
  (*the `/author/` folder is simply for illustration purposes. This folder does not exist.*)
- `([0-9]+)` == Numeric only value, saved in brackets to be used later as the first variable (`$1`) as reading left to right.
  `+` indicates greedy, takes as many characters (this case digits) as available before reaching a non-digit
- `/?` == Means an optional character (this case a slash)
- `(.*)` == brackets for 2nd saved string (`$2`), this time of any characters (`.`) for any length (`*`).
- `$` == dollar sign shows end of the URI string to be rewritten.

This will have a URI `/author/4/joe` which will load the page (hidden from the browser) `/author.php?author_id=4&author=joe` .

Other variations will be things like `/4-joe` or `/4joe` as URLs, etc. etc. each containing both pieces of required data for the `author.php` page.

Comment: OK. I get it now. Thanks for the explanation.